# HAproxy acl based on stick-table value

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to set up HAproxy to limit the amount of connections based on the source IP of the user connecting. I have set up a stick-table to monitor the amount of connections and can manually set a connection limit based on that.

However I want to load the ip -> max connections from a map file and use that, but I can seem to figure out how to equate the two. I can load the map and get it to put the max connections into the header to test that it's load the map correctly which works.

This is my config for the frontend (not working) that I have so far. Am I on the right track or is there even a way that I can do what I want to do.

```
frontend limit10
        bind *:8010
        stick-table type ip size 100k expire 30s store conn_cur
        tcp-request content track-sc0 src
        acl whitelist src -f /root/proxy/whitelist.txt
        use_backend error401 if !whitelist
        acl connection_limit src_conn_cur gt [src,map_ip(/root/proxy/maxCon.txt,0)]
        use_backend error429 if connection_limit
        use_backend webs
```